# Олимпиада по русскому языку

Tags: школьное-задание

В сети попалось фотография вопроса из олимпиады по русскому языку. Вопрос меня, мягко скажем, озадачил. Нет, конечно, у меня богатое воображение, и подвести какую-то базу можно под все. Но, честно говоря, я даже не могу представить, какое именно слово тут является лишним. Разве что, только, если рассуждать, что химик, яблоко и офтальмолог - это реально существующие... ммм... предметы, а единорог - существо сказочное. Других вариантов у меня нет.
У кого какие идеи?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... определив собственный алгоритм
> рассуждения

Если это для младших классов, то следовало бы как-то попроще формулировать. Например: "Какое слово лишнее и почему?"

Вообще, задание действительно странное. Логика ответа может быть любой. Вот, например, варианты, которые вполне могли бы предложить ученики младших классов:

химик - 1) единственное слово, начинающееся с согласной; 2) единственное слово, в котором нет буквы "о".

Варианты про яблоню женского рода и ее неодушевленность мне тоже нравятся.

Answer (score 3):

Это все же олимпиада по языку, а не по биологии... И не тест на IQ. Яблоня – женского рода.

А для каких классов? Это тоже важно.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения русского языка, лишним будет вариант *Яблоня*, так как, во-первых, это единственное неодушевлённое существительное, а во-вторых - единственное женского рода.

По всей видимости, задание предназначалось ученикам младших классов.

Answer (score 1):

Мне приходилось видеть похуже. Например, объяснить этимологию того или иного слова. Но даже профессор-лингвист может и не знать (вернее, не знает!!!) этимологию всех слов. Слова попадались достаточно трудные. Я поищу, если найду - напишу.

Comment: Может, это и не  к месту, но постоянно вижу, что модератор Виталина что-то изменяет, а что именно , и главное - зачем?

Comment: Поддержу.  
Виталина_PG, будьте добры, модерируйте форум с умом. Не надо исправлять чужие тексты.  
Поставила в известность владельца форума, надеюсь, вопрос решится.